# How to set key board input value into the function by using python

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci

Here is the Algorithm I have created for Fibonacci Sequence. In here I want to add my keyboard value for my python function. How can I do it. Here is the source code for it.

```
i = int(input("Please Enter the Position"))
def fibonacci(i):
       if i == 0:
           return 0

       elif i == 1:
           return 1

       else : 
           return fibonacci(i-2) + fibonacci(i-1)

print(fibonacci(3))
```

Comment: @j1-lee I want to given some value using key borad. Currently I am hardcoding that value like this "print(fibonacci(3)) "

Comment: Ah I see the `3` now. You can just use `print(fibonacci(i))` instead, since your `i` has the value the user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = int(input("Please Enter the Position"))
def fibonacci(i):
       if i == 0:
           return 0

       elif i == 1:
           return 1

       else : 
           return fibonacci(i-2) + fibonacci(i-1)

print(fibonacci(i))    #<--- here is your answer (i instead of 3 as i stores the keyboard input)
```